# Split one row in csv column to multiple rows keeping other columns same in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Suppose I have a csv file with 4 columns per row like this:

```
712,713,714,  26   blah   blah
```

I want to have the result like this :

```
712    26    blah    blah 

713    26    blah    blah 

714    26    blah    blah
```

Now I would read the csv file in python but how would I split the rows like that without changing other columns and then write the result into another csv file.

**p.s- I don't know pandas so I would use simple csv module**

Comment: "without changing other columns" - can you be more exact regarding "other columns"? 4th column?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes from 2nd to 4th column the data will be same , as I have explained in the code block example above, the first column values separated by comma will split up in multiple rows . See the above code block :)

Comment: show your initial coding efforts

Answer (score 2):

Straightforwardly with `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` objects:

Sample `test.csv`:

```
712,713,714,  26   blah   blah
1,2,3,  11   aaa   bbb
```

---

```
import csv

inp_fname = 'test.csv'
out_fname = 'transposed.csv'

with open(inp_fname, 'r', newline='') as in_csvfile, \
        open(out_fname, 'w', newline='') as out_csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(in_csvfile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(out_csvfile, delimiter='\t')

    for row in reader:
        for v in row[0].rstrip(',').split(','):
            writer.writerow([v] + row[1:])
```

The final `transposed.csv` file contents:

```
712 26  blah    blah
713 26  blah    blah
714 26  blah    blah
1   11  aaa bbb
2   11  aaa bbb
3   11  aaa bbb
```

Comment: Thanks , I already did it in an inefficient way, will look at your code and get back to you :)